# Mysql, double join that use the same table twice, but indirectly

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

*There are plenty of question about join on the same table, but I can't find something related to my problem*

I have two tables:

```
user (id, name)
friends (from, to)
```

And I have the following query. It is supposed to retrieve all users with their friends :

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, f.to, friend.id, friend.name
FROM user

LEFT JOIN friends f ON user.id = f.from
LEFT JOIN user friend ON  user.id = f.to
LIMIT 0, 200
```

It returns something like this:

```
id name from to id   name
1  bob  1    3  NULL NULL
1  bob  1    4  NULL NULL
2  toto 2    7  NULL NULL
```

The from and two are correct, but the second join doesn't seem to work. Do you have any ideas what is wrong with the second join ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, f.to, friend.id, friend.name
FROM user
LEFT JOIN friends f ON user.id = f.from
LEFT JOIN user friend ON friend.id = f.to
LIMIT 0, 200
```

Note that I replaced `user` with `friend` in the join condition.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks